# Strange C++ pointer new / delete issues

Tags: c++, pointers, free

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main (int args, char **argv) {
    char *data = new char(16);
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; ++i) {
        data[i] = i; // works fine when commented out, also fails when data[i] = 0
    }

    char *res = new char (10);
    delete[] res;
    return 0;
}
```

gives error, see for yourself: http://ideone.com/AgZhZB

```
*** glibc detected *** ./a.out: free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x09377018 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x75ee2)[0xb7519ee2]
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6(_ZdlPv+0x1f)[0xb76f751f]
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6(_ZdaPv+0x1b)[0xb76f757b]
./a.out[0x80485af]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf3)[0xb74bd4d3]
./a.out[0x80484b1]
```

I am without a clue. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Huh, not again please! Read more attentively next time...

Comment: Why the heck is this getting upvoted?

Comment: +1: Clearly stated problem, well indented code, entire error message, link to live example. All components of a good question are there.

Comment: @H2CO3 Sorry if I missed something, but re:"not again" - I didn't see any similar questions in the OP's question list.

Comment: Patrick, for future reference, `valgrind` would have indicated problems early on.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Replace

```
char *data = new char(16);
```

with

```
char *data = new char[16];
```

What you have right now allocates a single `char` and initializes it to `16`. To allocate an array, you have to use square brackets as shown above.

Similarly, replace

```
char *res = new char(10);
```

with

```
char *res = new char[10];
```

Comment: 9 Seconds for the answer, definitely +1!

Answer (score 3):

The correct behavior is, obviously, **not to use `new`**.

```
#include <vector>

int main () {
    std::vector<char> data{16};
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; ++i) {
        data.at(i) = i;
    }

    std::vector<char> res{10};
    return 0;
}
```

*Note: the `data{10}` notation is C++11 initialization syntax, it's mostly equivalent to `data(10)` but more easily parsed by the compiler.*

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that could be "strange" in your code is that you are invoking undefined behaviour, first through out of bounds access:

```
char *data = new char(16); // pointer to single char, value 16
for (int i = 0; i < 16; ++i) {
    data[i] = i; // out of bounds access: UNDEFINED BEHAVIOUR
}
```

Then, by calling `delete[]` when you need `delete`:

```
char *res = new char (10); // pointer to single char, value 10
delete[] res; // Oops, UNDEFINED BEHAVIOUR
```

When you get undefined behaviour, anything could happen. It doesn't have to be reproducible, so it can seem "strange".